singular matrix and number of eigenvectors
what is the relationship between the a singular matrix and the number of linearly independent eigenvectors?
i encountered this question in DE system, and here the number of linearly independent eigenvectors, i mean whether to form a fundamental set of solutions, which i assume for a n*n matrix, should be n linearly independent eigenvectors.

There is no relationship. You should check the algebraic and geometric multiplicity concepts.
